# Backbone collection.reset( data ) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

So in my app I am retrieving a set of data via jquery $.get method, and the trying to reset a collection with that data much like this,

```
var self = this;

$.get('/api/project/active', function(data) {
    self.dropdownListProjectCollection.reset(data);
});
```

`dropdownListProjectCollection` gets set in the initialize function that looks like this,

```
initialize: function() {
    $(window).on('resize', this.responsiveMenu);

    this.dropdownListProjectCollection = new app.ProjectCollection;

    console.log(this.dropdownListProjectCollection);

    this.dropdownListProjectCollection.on('reset', this.populateMenu, this);

    this.render();

    return this;
},
```

The `console.log` returns an empty collection.

What would I be getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`? The error is triggered by the,

`self.dropdownListProjectCollection.reset(data)` line.

Whats going on? It works perfectly in the rest of my app.

console.log of self inside the getActiveProjects method

```
r {cid: "view1", options: Object, $el: e.fn.e.init[1], el: div.contentwrap, dropdownListProjectCollection: ProjectCollection…}  
$el: e.fn.e.init[1]
cid: "view1"
dropdownListProjectCollection: ProjectCollection
el: div.contentwrap
options: Object
__proto__: s
```

and the console.log of self in the callback,

```
r {cid: "view1", options: Object, $el: e.fn.e.init[1], el: div.contentwrap, dropdownListProjectCollection: ProjectCollection…}
$el: e.fn.e.init[1]
cid: "view1"
dropdownListProjectCollection: ProjectCollection
el: div.contentwrap
options: Object
__proto__: s
```

dropdownListProjectCollection before the reset

```
    ProjectCollection {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _events: Object, constructor: function…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
length: 0
models: Array[0]
__proto__: ctor
```

PRoject Collection

```
    ProjectCollection = (function(_super) {

    __extends(ProjectCollection, _super);

    function ProjectCollection() {
      return ProjectCollection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    ProjectCollection.prototype.url = "/api/project/projects";

    ProjectCollection.prototype.model = app.Project;

    ProjectCollection.prototype.archived = function() {
      return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
        status: '3'
      }));
    };

    ProjectCollection.prototype.active = function() {
      return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
        status: '1'
      }));
    };

    ProjectCollection.prototype.pending = function() {
      return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
        status: '7'
      }))
    };

    ProjectCollection.prototype.completed = function() {
      return new ProjectCollection(this.where({
        status: '5'
      }));
    }

    ProjectCollection.prototype.comparator = function(model) {
      return -model.get("creation_date_unix");
    };

    ProjectCollection.prototype.search = function(searchTerm, filters) {
      var pattern, status = [];
      pattern = new RegExp(searchTerm, "gi");

      // Loop throught the filters and push there numeric value to an array.
      for (var k in filters) {
        if(k == "pending" && filters["pending"] == true) {
          var pending = this.pending();
        }
        if(k == "active" && filters["active"] == true) {
          var active = this.active();
        }
        if(k == "completed" && filters["completed"] == true) {
          var completed = this.completed();
        }
        if(k == "archived" && filters["archived"] == true) {
          var archived = this.archived();
        }
      }


      var filteredCollection = new ProjectCollection;

      if(pending !== undefined) {
        filteredCollection.add(pending.models);
      }
      if(active !== undefined) {
        filteredCollection.add(active.models);
      }
      if(completed !== undefined) {
        filteredCollection.add(completed.models);
      }
      if(archived !== undefined) {
        filteredCollection.add(archived.models);
      }

      if(searchTerm != "") {
        return _(filteredCollection.filter(function(project){
          return pattern.test(project.get("project_name") + project.get("client_name"));
        }));
      }

      return filteredCollection;






      /*// Filter the collection based on the status attribute of 
      // the model. If the value of a key is undefined (not met the criteria in the loop)
      // the value will be undefined and return empty (false).
      var filteredCollection = this.filter(function(project){
        return project.get("status") == status[0] ||
               project.get("status") == status[1] ||
               project.get("status") == status[2] ||
               project.get("status") == status[3] ;
      });

      console.log(filteredCollection);
      */



    };

    return ProjectCollection;

  })(app.BaseCollection);
```

Comment: are you sure `self` is the current view?

Comment: What do you mean? I have created created the var self in that view

Comment: you've created the `var self` inside the `initialize` method?, I'm just asking, because if you're doing the ajax get inside another method on which this is not bound to the current view than this might be the problem...

Comment: @muistooshort I have used var that = this also and still get the same error.

Comment: If you post the whole program in jsfiddle, we can take a closer look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MP6Cu/

Comment: on the code that you pasted you didnt copy the ProjectCollection, can you paste also how you declared this collection?

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(self)` inside of `getActiveProjects` right after the `var self = this;`?  Also put one inside of the callback in `$.get` before the reset and let us know what it thinks the value of self is.

Comment: @CalebJoshuaMingle please see update in question

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` means your `reset` is not a function, which means your `dropdownListProjectCollection` is not a real collection. Or at least it's modified and `reset` method is gone. Could you print the `dropdownListProjectCollection` inside the `get` method before you do the actual resetting?

Comment: @coderek please the edit at the end of the question.

Comment: which version is your backbone and please show us your `ProjectCollection` class.

Comment: @coderek project collection added to question it is Backbone 1.0.0

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If so this is a perfect chance to put a `debugger` in the callback (before you call `reset`) and see if `self. dropdownListProjectCollection.reset` exists.  If not there is something wrong with your inheritance or reset is getting blown away.

Answer (score 0):

can you change this

```
__extends(ProjectCollection, _super);
```

to

```
__extends(ProjectCollection.prototype, _super);
```

assuming you __extends is similar to underscore's `extend` methods